# Unable to annotate windows in GNU screen(Unix)

Tags: unix, gnu-screen

I have just started developing in Unix environment and playing with screens and emacs.
My question might be preliminary but am unable to find an answer online.
I am able to create new windows in my screen ; however I am unable annotate them.
I know the command in Ctrl+a A; but how does one execute this on the keyboard?
Sorry if this questions seems silly; but is there way I can combine the Ctrl+a combination into a custom command?

Comment: On the keyboard you can just type `C-a` `A`, but maybe you want to know how to do that on the command line with a Unix command?

Comment: Yes. Currently I m able to create and detach, but not able to annotate or detach-logout from a window. Any help?

Comment: Did you see my answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried

```
screen -X title bla
```

yet?

Comment: Thank you! It works; so to name each window you need to navigate to it and name it?

Comment: manpage of `screen` says that you can use option `-p` to preselect a window (given by name or number).  So you can use sth like `screen -X -p 0 title null` to set the name of the window with number 0 to 'null'.